# Length of an integer with leading zeros in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to find length of an integer. There are many solutions for that, I have used `(int(math.log10(TheNumber))+1)`. But if the number is '0111', it returns as '1' in python 2.7 and in python 3.* it returns `'SyntaxError: leading zeroes in a decimal number is not permitted'`. But '0111' is '111'. But using `len(str(number))` is giving the correct length. Any solutions for this..

Just want to have an clarification about this. Thanks in advance

Sorry for little information in the question.
The question is,
0111 ,length of this number is 3, but when I check the length of this integer, in python 2.7,it return 2.
Code is

```
a = 0111

print(len(str(a)))
```

it returns 2 as the answer,
when I run the above same code in python3.* it shows as `SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`.

In my program, if user gives this kind of number,i.e numbers which has leading zeroes, how should I convert it into a number which has no leading zeroes in it.

my_input = 0111

converted_input =111

In python 2.7 it is considered as Octal number, when I print it, it returns `73`
In python 3.* it is asking for Octal representation(SyntaxError).
If I use another method `int(math.log10(TheNumber))+1`

```
import math
a = 0111
print(int(math.log10(a))+1)
```

In python 2.7 it returns 2,converts into octal number implicitly.
In python 3.* it return Syntax Error. So,any solutions for this will do good or If I am wrong, please point out. Thanks in advance

Comment: `’0111’` is a string not an integer. Just use `len(number)` if you want it to return `4`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the length of an integer".

Comment: I think it’s customary to think of the length of an integer as the number of digits in a given base. Maybe that’s not universal?

Comment: Perhaps, but it's important to turn beginners away from thinking in such terms. It is vital to understand the difference between what things actually are, and mere *representations of* those things.

Comment: Abisake - it would help if you paste (the relevant parts of) your actual code, particularly the lines where you assign the number to a variable and where you then call the function to obtain the length. From just the description, there is uncertainty about how you managed to do len(str(number)) if you are not using valid syntax for the value of the number.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel actually I couldn't understand 'There is no such thing as "the length of an integer"'. If i want to know how many digits of a integer, I should know it's length right?.If I am wrong please point out.

Comment: Integers don't have digits. Also: you can't eat the word "banana".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SyntaxError` is due to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/ — which basically made Python 3 stop silently interpreting 0-prefixed numbers as octal (which is what Python 2 does).

And indeed `0o111` (that is, 111 in octal) evaluates to 73 in decimal.

Your question doesn't give much information of what kind of length you're looking at — and what you need to do with it. But if you want to know how many decimal digits a number is composed of, you can do something like:

```
len(int(number_as_string, 10))
```

This will make sure that even `'0111'` is interpreted in decimal (that is, 111).

Comment: The question already states that `len(str(number))` is working. Obviously he would not have been able to assign `number` from a constant in the code without using valid syntax for that constant, and to be honest, there is considerable uncertainty about exactly what the OP has done, as he has not posted his exact code. In any case, clearly at *some* point he has tried to use `0111` and got a `SyntaxError` for the reasons you give.

Comment: It is also unclear whether the `'0111'` in the question represents an actual string in the code or just single quotes that he added in the question, although there is no mention of a `TypeError` being obtained from `math.log10`.

Comment: Regarding your answer, `len(int(number_as_string, 10))` will not work. You would need `len(str(int(number_as_string, 10)))` as you cannot call `len` directly on an `int`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, as `len(str(int(number_as_string,10)))` gives correct answer.